# R Shiny text output gets displayed like console output instead of text in a rmarkdown generated PDF download

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to render a PDF document via ramrkdown from the results of my Shiny App. However I have the problem that all text outputs show up in the downloaded documents as they would in the console eg. "[1] example" instead of "example". I tried everything I could think of but can't find the solution. Since in the app the text output is reactive and is different for every user I can't write it directly into the rmd.document either.

```
#LIBRARIES
library (shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library (shinyjs)
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library(rmarkdown)
library (knitr)



blues <- c( "#013560", "#0065AD", "#007BD3", "#0091F9", "#9FD4F9",  "#EEEEEE")



#sidebar vordefinieren
Codepan <-   div( 
  id = 'sidebar_cr',
  actionButton (inputId = "Button", label = "Go!"),
  "some intro text and then the download button",
  downloadButton("report", "Meine Ergebnisse als PDF speichern")
)




sidebar <- 
  dashboardSidebar(Codepan)


#Body vordefinieren

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  
  
  
  fluidRow(
    
    box(title = "Deine Mediennutzung",
        status= "success", solidHeader = TRUE, height=400,width = 11,
        plotOutput(outputId= "plotM", height= 300))
    
    
  ),
  
  
  
  fluidRow(
    box(
      width = 11, title = "Deine Ergebnisse",  solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
      column(width= 6, textOutput("text"))
    ))
)




# hier beginnt die eigentliche App:
ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "title", disable = FALSE),
    sidebar,
    body
  )



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  #2 Plot comparison Feedback
  
  
  
  plotM <- eventReactive(input$Button, {
    det <-data.frame(group = c("a-du", "a-ges", "b-sport", "c-age"),
                     means = c(16, 22, 31, 15)
    )
    ggplot(det, aes(x = group, y = means)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#013560", color = "#013560") +
      # scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Du", "Gesamtdurchschnitt",paste("Durchschnitt",Daten[toupper(input$Code), "Sportart_zurueckkodiert"]), paste("Durchschnitt", (Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]-1),"-",(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]+1), "Jahre" )))+ 
      xlab(NULL) + 
      ylab("Mediennutzung in Minuten")+
      #geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(as.character(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "Nutzungsdauer_DM_Gesamt"])), lty = 8, col = "Red")+
      geom_text(aes(label = round(means, 0)), vjust =2, colour = "white", size= 8)#+
    #geom_label(label="Du", x = 0.5,y = as.numeric(as.character(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "Nutzungsdauer_DM_Gesamt"])), color ="red")
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$plotM <- renderPlot({
    plotM()
  })
  
  
  
 text <-  eventReactive(input$Button, {
  "Some random text."
 })
 
 output$text<- renderText({
   text()
 })
  
  
  
  output$report<-
    
    downloadHandler(
      "Results.pdf",
      content = 
        function(file){
          rmarkdown::render(
            input= "report_file2.Rmd",
            output_file = "built_report.pdf",
            params = list (plotM = plotM(),
                           text= text())
          )
          readBin (con = "built_report.pdf",
                   what = "raw",
                   n = file.info ("built_report.pdf")[, "size"])%>%
            writeBin (con = file)
        } )
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

RMD file:

````
---
title: "Parameterized Report for Shiny"
output: pdf_document
params:
  plotM: 'NULL'
  text: 'NULL'
---
RMD:
```{r, echo = FALSE}
params[["plotM"]]```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
params[["text"]]```
````

Comment: You can try to use the `cat` or `sprintf` functions to format your text

Comment: Well thanks again